# How to pull photos with ADB from local storage - android device

Tags: android, adb, photos, pull

i have some problems with my Asus Zenfone 2 device (no root).

In particular, some days ago, while i was travelling abroad, my device decided to no more turn on, staying permanently in the loading ASUS screen.

Before doing the hard reset, i want to try to save at least all my photos located in the internal storage (N.B: i do not have an external SDCARD).

i correctly set up the ADB software to recognize my device but i am not able to find the photo directory.

Till now i have only pull successfully 2 directory: "sys" and "cache", using this command:

```
adb pull / C:\Myfile
```

It seems to transfer only some file system.

Doas anyone know how to pull photos or other file?

Comment: adb pull /sdcard/DCIM/ C:\MyFiles\

Comment: just tried with "adb pull /sdcard/"....0 files pulled. 0 files skipped...i don't understand why i can't see the files... the phone is not rooted of course.

Answer (score 40):

Use `adb pull sdcard/DCIM/Camera C:\MyFile`

If it didn't work use:

```
adb shell
echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

It will print path to your simulated external storage. Then:

```
cd $EXTERNAL_STORAGE/DCIM
ls
```

It will print folder which will contain camera app folders. Lastly, use:

```
adb pull HERE_PUT_PATH_TO_EXTERNAL/DCIM/SELECTED_CAMERA_APP_FOLDER C:\MyFiles
```

Note: To leave `adb shell` type `exit`

Comment: i am not able to use "adb shell". this is the error: exec '/system/bin/sh' failed: No such file or directory (2).

Comment: It looks like shell is missing (that's bad). I guess the memory is completely corrupted. The `adb pull /sdcard/` should download something, but it looks like there is just nothing to download.

Comment: it fails also using "push text.txt /sdcard", saying "permission denied". Probably i need root permits to access the sdcard. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

I did 3 things to pull all files of the same type, in this case *.mp4 (all videos)

**1. First copy the output of: {all videos listed} with xargs to a file.txt**

```
adb shell ls /storage/7C17-B4FD/DCIM/Camera/*.mp4 | xargs -t -I % echo % >> file.txt
```

`adb shell ls /storage/7C17-B4FD/DCIM/Camera/*.mp4` returns all videos listed in device.
The argument `-t` show the output from XARGS, and `-I` lets you use a variable, in this case represented with `%` then you write the command you want to do. In this case, `echo %` each line and add it to the file.txt

**2. You need to clean the file.txt from spaces and the `'\r'` you do it with the command `tr`**

```
tr -d '\r' < file.txt > text-clean.txt
```

the input file is `< file.txt` and the new output file is `> text-clean.txt`

**3.Now you can `cat` the new clean file `text-clean.txt` and use that input with XARGS command to pass the command `adb pull` for each file.**

```
cat text-clean.txt | xargs -t -I % adb pull % ./
```

we `cat` the content of `text-clean.txt` and send the output to XARGS, then we see what is the result of command with `-t` and `-I` to add variables. `adb pull` to request file from path which is represented with `%` and `./` means copy to this directory or currrent directory of where you are.

if you just need to copy one file. just need to find the file with `adb shell ls /path/to/file`  and the just copy to your location with `adb pull`. example

```
adb pull /storage/7C717-B4FD/DCIM/Camera/video1.mp4 ./
```